# Query about the equilibrium of mixing gases and chemical potential

Tags: thermodynamics

In the following lecture : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cc2l1QTTZA4&list=PLA62087102CC93765&index=15, at 5:53, the lecturer begins to write the equilibrium conditions of the experiment. The experiment is described as a container which contains 3 separate sections. Section 1 containing particles of gas A, section 2 containing particles of gas B and the 3rd again containing particles of gas A. 
The wall between between sections 1 and 2 is broken and the gases have mixed together completely. The boundary between the two remaining sections allows for the diffusion of the gases.

My question is that, why in equilibrium is it that the partial pressure of A in the mixed section equals the pressure of the pure section?

Surely in equilibrium it's simply that:

pressure on the LHS  = pressure on the RHS.
Which is the same as saying:

partial pressure of gas A in mixed section + partial pressure of gas B in mixed section = pressure of gas A in pure section.

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

> Surely in equilibrium it's simply that:
>
> pressure on the LHS = pressure on the RHS. Which is the same as saying:
>
> partial pressure of gas A in mixed section + partial pressure of gas B in mixed section = pressure of gas A in pure section.

This is not correct reasoning. In mechanical equilibrium, the forces acting on a small section of the barrier separating two parts of a container have to add up to zero. For a rigid barrier, this would usually imply that the *total* pressures on its two sides have to equal. But here the barrier is explicitly said to be an elastic membrane. Once curved, the tension of the membrane tips the force balance, as a result of which the pressure must be higher on the convex side of the membrane (the side where the surrounding gas fills a convex domain). This is very similar to the effects of surface tension, where, for instance, the pressure of air just above a convex surface of a liquid is higher than the pressure of the liquid just below the surface.

As to your other statement:

> My question is that, why in equilibrium is it that the partial pressure of A in the mixed section equals the pressure of the pure section?

Think of the equilibrium from the point of view of detailed balance. In (ideal) gases, the pressure on a surface is proportional to the number of molecules that impact on a unit area of the surface per unit of time. The equality of *partial* pressures of the gas A is thus equivalent to requiring that the numbers of molecules of A impacting on the membrane are the same on both sides of the membrane. If this were not the case, then there would be net transport of the gas A through the membrane (assuming that the membrane is symmetric with respect to the transport of molecules from one side to the other), in contradiction to the assumption that the system is in equilibrium.

Note how the argument is tailored to the situation at hand. In the more common case of a rigid barrier, the total pressures on its two sides must equal, regardless of the chemical composition of the gas on the two sides. In our situation here, this mechanical balance argument cannot be used due to the a priori unknown tension of the membrane. The detailed equilibrium argument, on the other hand, is insensitive to the presence of other gases than A, as long as these cannot pass through the membrane. The partial pressure of such other gases (B in the described situation) only affects the curvature of the membrane.